# Testing Active Directory users and groups

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, virtual-machines, testing, virtualization

I have an Active Directory instance set up on a VM, and have set up a number of users and groups. I was wondering how I would go about testing this instance e.g. testing the connection, and verifying the users and groups.

Thanks.

Comment: Testing what connection? Verifying the users and groups in what way?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you

1. Create a user in the new domain
2. create a second VM with a client OS (Win7, WinSvr)
3. connect the client to the domain and,
4. login with the user account created in #1